# ClassCastException: com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General cannot be cast t o javax.crypto.CipherSpi on Karaf 4.2.5

Tags: apache-karaf, jce

We are using Apache karaf 4.2.5. We are using AES encryption algorithm in our application. And the javax.crypto package is present in the Karaf etc/jre.properties for java 1.8.

We get the ClassCastException when we call `Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");`

Exception in thread "Thread-33" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General cannot be cast to javax.crypto.CipherSpi
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:137)

The karaf bundle that has this code does import the javax.crypto package. Could any one point out what i am missing here.

Thanks & regards.
Dheeraj

Comment: I have the same issue, have you figured out what was causing it?

Comment: We had a bundle that exports * in pom.xml file, which also exports the javax.crypto.* packages. Which was not needed, so removing them and exporting only packages within the bundle resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to export nothing you already import, because if two callers uses different exporter of the same packages, classes created will be bound to their respective ClassLoader (each bundle has its own) and ClassCastException can occurs if two identical classes from different ClassLoader are used interchangeably